# How to center horizontal/vertical in IE?

Tags: html, css

Here's the page I'm working on:

http://www.escalateinternet.com/

I'm trying to center the login form both vertically and horizontally.  It's working in all browsers right now except for Internet Explorer.

Here's the CSS I added to the div to center it:

```
bottom: 0;
height: 400px;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
```

What am I doing wrong for it to not be centered in IE like it is in other browsers?

Comment: Version 11 is what I checked it in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `div` with those classes: `whmcscontainer contentpadded` put css `width:100%`. IE needs parent's width for reference to set position with `margin: auto`.

Comment: What I was about to say

Answer (score 2):

```
bottom: 0;
height: 400px;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
text-align:center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you do not have DOCTYPE declairation, this error occured. add this line above html tag. At the top of document. 
`<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: You do realize `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration doesn't fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
element.style {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 400px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: auto auto auto -150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```